# Meteor-Now Deployment Error "sh: meteor: not found"

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, zeit-pkg

I have problems deploying my meteor app with meteor-now. I followed this tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@purplecones/deploying-a-meteor-app-for-free-using-zeit-now-c183329057c9). I also tried deploying with [ZEIT's](https://zeit.co/download) OSX Client but it always throws the same error. 
 Does anyone know a workaround? 
[image: Build Errors shown here]

Edit 1:
This is my package.json

```
 {
  "name": "helloworld",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the output from the rest of the log file at that path?

Comment: You have `meteor` installed globally?

Comment: Can you please also add the commands you typed in your terminal prior to the error? I also noticed that the guide's terminal outputs some lines about docker, yours not. Did you exactly repeated the steps from the guide?

Comment: @rlated did my answer helped you in any way with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

With transition to now v. 2.0 there is basically no more option to use it with Meteor. See also the thread on `meteor-now` and 2.0:

> jkrup commented on 9 Nov 2018
>
> Unfortunately with the current planned direction of Now, you're correct that it indicates MeteorJS will become essentially incompatible with Now.
>
> However, I won't let that be the end to this project. Which will remain the easiest/zero-config way to deploy meteor apps. I've actually have already experimented with deploys on a different platform that starts very cheap (
>
> I'll also try to reach out to some people at Zeit and see if they can help come up with a solution as well. @timneutkens

https://github.com/jkrup/meteor-now/issues/133

You can also read more in the migration guide: https://zeit.co/docs/v2/platform/upgrade-to-2-0/

Okay so I tried to switch my platform to now 1 but for my account this is already not working anymore. The option is on https://zeit.co/account already disabled:

[image: disabled platform switch on zeit account page]

If you are able to still use platform v.1 you may configure in your `package.json` a property `"now": { ... }` or add a `now.json` and [configure your now service](https://zeit.co/docs/v1/) there.

If you configure using `now.json` you may place it in your project root and also run `meteor-now ... --local-config`.